# How do I control if an ajax webform has errors?

Tags: 7, ajax, webforms

I have a webform that sends an email upon submission. Ajax is enabled so when I hit submit and there are errors on the form they will show instantly. However if there are no errors I would like to hide the form along with the success message.

Some pseudo code (sort of):

```
Drupal.behaviors.sendMail = {
  attach: function (context) {

    $('#webform-client-form-340', context).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
      if ($('.alert-errors').length == 1) {
        thisForm.highLight()
      } else {
        thisForm.hide();
      }
    });

  }
};
```

This doesn't work because the .alert-errors div is not yet there on ajaxComplete. 
So how do I check for errors, highlight the form if they are present and otherwise hide the form?

Comment: So I got a hack to work at least. If there are errors the xhr response will be valid json otherwise not so I'm doing a try and catch on `$.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)` and hide the form if the json doesn't parse.

Answer (score 0):

I when I normally have to debug this I use

[Debugging ajax with FIREPHP](http://www.thecarneyeffect.co.uk/how-debug-ajax-drupal-using-firephp)

> Explaines how you can debug ajax with FIREPHP